# how to change my pdf viewer library in android

Tags: java, android, pdf

i have one pdf viewer which i have downloaded from here :https://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/andpdf with svn
it's working fine in emulator..but it dosen't have feature of seraching any text like we do in adobe pdf reader.so i want to add text view searching feature in it,can any one tell me how to do it?i am new to android and i don't no too much about it,and if i need to change my library for it than what library i should use and from where i can get it..please help me to solve it if any one knows about it...
Thanks in Advance 
Aamirkhan I.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android